# Pynput script does not return an output with escape key

Tags: python, pynput

I have been using Pynput lately in order to try out some new programs. In one such program, I am intending on opening a webpage whenever the mouse is clicked it opens a webpage (more or less a bit of a joke program, but one that I will probably use as assistance to some other Pynput program). The opening of a webpage whenever the mouse is clicked works well, but the killswitch that I am trying to implement is not. The script returns absolutely nothing when escape is clicked.

I am pretty new to Pynput in general, so I'm not incredible at it. I suspect that the issue may be in the 'listener1' block at the end. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pynput import mouse
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import webbrowser
def on_release(key):
    if str(key) == Key.esc:
        quit()
def on_click (x, y, button, pressed):
    webbrowser.open('[website]')
listener1 = mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click)
listener1.start()
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I would like for the program to open a webpage in the place of [website]. Any assistance in fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about pynput, but it looks like you have no flow control for your open browser command.

Perhaps it should look like:

```
def on_click (x, y, button, pressed):    
     listener1.start()
     with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as
     listener:listener.join()
     listener1 = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
     if listener1:
          webbrowser.open('[website]')
     else:
          break
```

Comment: So far the web browser opening seems to be working fine. The problem that is appearing seems to be related to the killswitch. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am a little late to this but maybe it still helps somebody. You simply forgot to use quotation marks around the Key.esc after converting key to a string. Using:

`if str(key) == 'Key.esc':`

should work just fine.

I would also recomend you to use `return False` before the `quit()` because otherwise the listener thread will not be fully stopped and might contine to run.

Comment: I'd probably even suggest not to convert the key to a string.

Comment: How did you assume that `str(key)` will be this specific string `'Key.esc'`? The variable `Key.esc` might be holding a string.